# Warnings when running Bobcat 2.X project

Tags: gradle

When I run a Bobcat 2.X project I see 3 warnings, these I want to resolve.

Warning 3:
I get an "STANDARD_ERROR" the test passes, but in the logging there is the text "STANDARD_ERROR"

```
be.vrt.aem.vrtnws.HomePageTest > bSiteHeaderMenuNavigationTest() STANDARD_ERROR
    Starting ChromeDriver 73.0.3683.20 (8e2b610813e167eee3619ac4ce6e42e3ec622017) on port 33451
    Only local connections are allowed.
    Please protect ports used by ChromeDriver and related test frameworks to prevent access by malicious code.
    feb 12, 2019 6:12:40 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
    INFO: Detected dialect: OS
```

Warning 2:
`warning javax.* types are not being woven because the weaver option '-Xset:weaveJavaxPackages=true' has not been specified`

Warning 3:

```
Please protect ports used by ChromeDriver and related test frameworks to prevent access by malicious code.
```